# Error 403 in the installation of MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

I have an error when trying to install MySQL server using "mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.11.0".

I have a 403 error for downloading the "MySQL Server 8.0.11" package.

Can you help me solve this problem?

Here is an image of the error during the installation :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK0p6.png)

Thank you in advance for your help.